# Any way to sync only music with ipod classic 160gb

Tags: itunes, ipod

Is their a way to sync just the music from my iTunes library to my iPod classic? Right now it also syncs videos and I don't want them taking up space on my iPod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by accident.

If you click on your iPod in iTunes, and then you select movies at the top, you can uncheck "sync movies".